# I want to seperate the entered string as indian money format like if i entered 123456 means, then i want to get 1,23,456

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to separate the entered string as indian money format like if i entered 123456 means, then i want to get 1,23,456:

The code iam using is:

```
function addCommas(x)
{

var parts=x.toString().split(".");

parts[0]=parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

return parts.join(".");`enter code here

}
```

it gives answer as 123,456.

**I want output as 1,23,456**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *RegExp* solution would use [positive lookaheads `(?=pattern)`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure the sequence is in the correct part of the String

You need to match 1 or 2 `\d` (digits) where

- It is followed by zero or more groups of 2 digits `(?:\d{2})*`
- Which is followed by a group of 3 digits and the end of the string `\d{3}$`

So you'd write a *RegExp* lke this `/(\d\d?)(?=(?:\d{2})*\d{3}$)/`, and in usage

```
'1234567890'.replace(/(\d\d?)(?=(?:\d{2})*\d{3}$)/g, '$1,');
// "1,23,45,67,890"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this out

```
var formattedCurrencyFunc = function(){
  function currencyFormat(num) {
    return num.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
  }

    $(".formattedCurrency").each(function () {
      var $currSpan = $(this).text(),
      $currFormatted = currencyFormat(parseFloat($currSpan));
      $(this).removeClass('formattedCurrency');
      $(this).html($currFormatted);
    });
}


formattedCurrencyFunc()
```

The full working demo on codepen

http://codepen.io/harishgadiya/pen/pgZpXN

Comment: Thanks.. @harish gadiya